# Draw 3d contours on scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, contour

I have a dataset where each row corresponds to an x,y and z value.

I would like to create a 2d scatterplot of variables x and y and overlay the 2d contours of the 3 dimensional space.

I tried the following:

```
load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ya5g2n47al2cn1j/df.Rdata?dl=0")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$x,y=df$y,color=df$z))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_contour(aes(z=df$z))
```

but I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
Not possible to generate contour data
```

Is there a way to do this? Most examples I could find online use similar data of x, y, z form

Here's how the data looks:

```
> head(df)
           x         y             z
1 0.15395671 0.1548728 -9.622222e-02
2 0.18148413 0.1554308 -1.091111e-01
3 0.07870902 0.1538021 -2.911111e-02
4 0.13514970 0.1134729 -1.133333e-01
5 0.03504008 0.1053258  4.222222e-03
6 0.02161680 0.1140364 -1.110223e-16
```

Comment: Can you show what the df looks like? Showing a few rows so it's clear what the data looks like might help sort this.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your data may not have a value of z for each possible combination of x and y values; you could not have a matrix that is "x" rows and "y columns and have a value of z at each index, you would have gaps. You may still be able to get what you want with `geom_density_2d()`, however. Given your example data above:

```
x<-c(0.15395671, 0.18148413, 0.07870902, 0.1351497, 0.03504008, 0.0216168)
y<-c(0.1548728, 0.1554308, 0.1538021, 0.1134729, 0.1053258, 0.1140364)
z<-c(-0.09622222, -0.1091111, -0.02911111, -0.1133333, 0.004222222, 0)

xyz <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(xyz, aes(x, y, z = z) ) + geom_density_2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do the 3d contours. Would it be possible to do it using interpolation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could interpolate to fill your matrix with values, but you'd probably be filling a lot of gaps to the point that it might not be useful. That said, I don't know your data! Maybe you're not missing that many z values for x-y pairs.